# Check multiple checkboxes with one global funtion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to select a list of checkboxes. The inputs are generated dynamically and there is more than one list of checkboxes - so I created a global function by sending in the id of the < table > so that the correct list of checkboxes are checked/unchecked.
I think the looping of the nodes in the nodelist is causing the problem but in my mind, it makes sense, but the checkboxes are not checking and there is no error popping up either.

```js
function checkAll(name) {
  var nodeList = $(name).next('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var nodes = $(nodeList);
  nodes.each(function(node) {
    if (!node.disabled) {
      node.checked = true;
    }
  }); 
}
```

```html
<table summary="User locations" id="LocationsTable">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type='hidden' name='StoreSelector' id='StoreSelector' value='true'>
      Other locations (multi-store)
      <button type="button" onclick="javascript:checkAll('LocationsTable');">All</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="javascript:uncheckAll('LocationsTable');">None</button>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="LocationRow">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store" value="Store">&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 1</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find here very well.
Consider that your name is an ID, so put in fron of your *name* the hashtag *#name*.
Also I would recommend using an event listener. I updated your code to use it therefore I gave your btn an id.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){checkAll('LocationsTable')})


function checkAll(name) {
  var nodeList = [...$(`#${name}`).find('input[type="checkbox"]')];
  nodeList.forEach(function(node) {

    if (!node.disabled) {
      node.checked = true;
    }
  }); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table summary="User locations" id="LocationsTable">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type='hidden' name='StoreSelector' id='StoreSelector' value='true'>
      Other locations (multi-store)
      <button id='btn' type="button" >All</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="javascript:uncheckAll('LocationsTable');">None</button>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="LocationRow">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store" value="Store">&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 1</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store" value="Store">&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 1</span>

      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store" value="Store">&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 1</span>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) :

```js
function checkAll(name)
  {
  document.querySelectorAll(`#${name} input[type=checkbox]`).forEach(nod=>
    {
    if (!nod.disabled) nod.checked = true;
    }); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to prepend the selector passed to the functions with a `#` - an `id selector`. Then all you need in the function is:

```
$(name).find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':disabled').prop('checked',true);
```

**DEMO**

```js
function checkAll(name) {
    $(name).find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':disabled').prop('checked',true);
}
function uncheckAll(name) {
  $(name).find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':disabled').prop('checked',false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table summary="User locations" id="LocationsTable">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type='hidden' name='StoreSelector' id='StoreSelector' value='true'>
      Other locations (multi-store)
      <button type="button" onclick="javascript:checkAll('#LocationsTable');">All</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="javascript:uncheckAll('#LocationsTable');">None</button>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="LocationRow">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store1" value="Store">&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 1</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store2" value="Store">&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 2</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store3" value="Store">&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 3</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store4" value="Store" disabled>&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 4</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**OPTION 2**

However, I would not advise use of inline JS. Separate your JS, CSS, and HTML as in the following demo:

```
$('button.all').on('click', function() {
    //this refers to button.all
    $(this)
    //go up the tree to select the table
    .closest('table')
    //go down to the checkboxes and check them
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':disabled').prop('checked',true);
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$('button.all').on('click', function() {
    //this refers to button.all
    $(this)
    //go up the tree to select the table
    .closest('table')
    //go down to the checkboxes and check them
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':disabled').prop('checked',true);
});

$('button.none').on('click', function() {
    //this refers to button.none
    $(this)
    //select tabl
    .closest('table')
    //select checkbox and uncheck
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':disabled').prop('checked',false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table summary="User locations" id="LocationsTable">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type='hidden' name='StoreSelector' id='StoreSelector' value='true'>
      Other locations (multi-store)
      <button type="button" class="all">All</button>
      <button type="button" class="none">None</button>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="LocationRow">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store1" value="Store">&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 1</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store2" value="Store">&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 2</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store3" value="Store">&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 3</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store4" value="Store" disabled>&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 4</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**OPTION 3**

Alternatively, you can use one button to toggle all the checkboxes.

```
$('button.toggle').on('click', function() {
    //this refers to button.all
    $(this)
    //go up the tree to select the table
    .closest('table')
    //go down to the checkboxes and check them
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':disabled').prop('checked',function() {return !this.checked});
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$('button.toggle').on('click', function() {
    //this refers to button.all
    $(this)
    //go up the tree to select the table
    .closest('table')
    //go down to the checkboxes and check them
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':disabled').prop('checked',function() {return !this.checked});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table summary="User locations" id="LocationsTable">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type='hidden' name='StoreSelector' id='StoreSelector' value='true'>
      Other locations (multi-store)
      <button type="button" class="toggle">All</button>
      <!--button type="button" class="none">None</button-->
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="LocationRow">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store1" value="Store">&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 1</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store2" value="Store">&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 2</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store3" value="Store">&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 3</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Store" id="Store4" value="Store" disabled>&nbsp;<span id="StoreName">Store 4</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**NOTE**

Please note that in each option no reference is made to the `id` of the particular table in question as the event handler keeps the actions within the particular table whose button was clicked.